# Move ConfigurationSection

Tags: java, bukkit

I made a storage system for game-arenas and their cordinates/names etc. and I numbered them from `1` to `n` . Now I have to remove one of these arenas `0 < i <= n` A sample of the config looks like this:

```
'3':
  Arena:
    Name: AirConflict
    Teams: 2
    PlayersPerTeam: 4
    World: AirConflict
    Spec:
      World: AirConflict
      X: 100
      ...
```

Lets say '2' has been deleted. So now I have to move every further arenas to the number one less. '3' has to come '2'.

I storaged the amount of arenas. Here is what I have so far:

```
int ac = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
arena.set(ac + "", null);
int arenas = arena.getInt("Arenacounts");
arena.set("Arenacounts", (arenas -1));
for (int i = ac+1; i <= arenas; i ++) {
    //TODO move all the arenas                  
}
```

How can I now easily just move all the other entrys instead of rewriting them? `arena` is the configuration-file which is storaged this way:

```
public File file = new File("plugins/Arenas", "arena.yml");
public FileConfiguration arena = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
```

**EDIT**

Since noone understands what I really want or what I have I will show you here:

I have this config:

```
Arenacount: 3
'1':
    Whatever_1:
'2':
    Whatever_2:
'3':
    Whatever_3:
```

Now I want to remove the 2nd entry and the file should then look like this:

```
Arenacount: 2
'1':
    Whatever_1:
'2':
    Whatever_3:
```

Answer (score 1):

If actually entry numbers have not gap between them (1,2,3,4, etc...), you should change the design of your configuration file : remove the number from it.

When you load the configuration file, you can deduce the number of the entry by its appearing order in the List.

In this way when you remove one entry and you want to store the information in the configuration file, you just need to delete this entry.

EDIT with your example :

Instead of using this configuration file :

```
Arenacount: 3
'1':
    Whatever_1:
'2':
    Whatever_2:
'3':
    Whatever_3:
```

Use this configuration file :

```
Arenacount: 3
    Whatever_1:
    Whatever_2:
    Whatever_3:
```

So after deleting the second element you should have :

```
Arenacount: 3
    Whatever_1:       
    Whatever_3:
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanna delete '2' out of '1','2','3','4' and then move '3' to '2' and '4' to '3' so there is no gap

Comment: Great. So why do you just need to remove the number from the configuration file ?

Comment: I don't know how to overwrite all the subsomponents. If I remove 2 I don't want to have a gap. I want to move '3' to '2' and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I understand but you have just to remove the number in your actual configuration file . For example : remove '1' 2' '3', properties in the configuration file.

Comment: so if the config looks like this:

Arenacount: 2
'1':
    something_0:
'2':
    something_1:

and then I remove '1' it will automatically set '2': to '1': only by doing 'arena.set("1", null);'?

Comment: No I don't refer to that. I propose you to change the design of the configuration file. You don't need to specify number in the file. I edited with your example.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't assign them a number.

```
Arenacount:
    ArenaName1:
    ArenaName2:
```